# Issues with multiple p5.image

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I'm playing around with creating some optical art with p5 and I'm running into issues with the `image` function. This is mt sketch.js file:

```
import Tile from "./Tile.js";

new p5(p5 => {

    const rows = 14;
    const columns = 14;
    const dimension = 40
    const height = rows * dimension;
    const width = columns * dimension;
    const framerate = 1;
    const tiles = [];

    p5.setup = () => {
        p5.createCanvas(width, height);
        p5.frameRate(framerate);
        for (let r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
            for (let c = 0; c < columns; c++) {
                tiles.push(new Tile(p5, c * dimension, r * dimension, dimension, r, c));
            }
        }
    };

    p5.draw = () => {
        p5.background(200);
        tiles.forEach((tile) => {
            console.log(tile);
            p5.image(tile.update(), tile.x, tile.y);
        });
    };
});
```

And this is Tile.js:

```
export default class Tile {

    constructor(p5, x, y, dimension, row, column) {
        this.p5 = p5;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.dimension = dimension;
        this.row = row;
        this.column = column;
        this.onFirst = true;
        this.on = p5.color(255, 184, 0);
        this.off = p5.color(26, 17, 16);
        this.diameter = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(dimension, 2) * 2)
        this.pg = this.p5.createGraphics(dimension, dimension)
        this.pg.noStroke();
    }

    update() {
        if (this.diameter < 0) {
            this.diameter = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(this.dimension, 2) * 2);
            this.onFirst = !this.onFirst
        }
        else {
            this.diameter -= 1;
        }
        return this.draw();
    }

    draw() {
        this.pg.fill(this.onFirst ? this.off : this.on);
        this.pg.rect(this.x, this.y, this.dimension, this.dimension);
        this.pg.fill(this.onFirst ? this.on : this.off);
        this.pg.circle(this.x + this.dimension / 2, this.y + this.dimension / 2, this.diameter);
        return this.pg;
    }
}
```

While I starting out I just had the one image and that was displayed on the top left as I wanted... subsequent images are not though, artefacts appear in odd places though (as you can see here: https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/Lbs9v8f4/). I've tried all sorts of things like exporting the image as a Base64 image and using `loadImage` but I think I might've been barking up the wrong tree.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, the method `Tile.draw` draws to an image (`.pg`) with a size of (`.dimension`, `.dimension`) rather than the canvas. 
So the the origin has to be (0, 0) rather than (`.x`, `.y`), because the final image (`.pg`) is placed on the canvas at (`.x`, `.y`).

Change the code as follows, to solve the issue:

```js
draw() {
    this.pg.fill(this.onFirst ? this.off : this.on);

    // this.pg.rect(this.x, this.y, this.dimension, this.dimension);
    this.pg.rect(0, 0, this.dimension, this.dimension); 

    this.pg.fill(this.onFirst ? this.on : this.off);

    // this.pg.circle(this.x + this.dimension / 2, this.y + this.dimension / 2, this.diameter);
    this.pg.circle(this.dimension / 2, this.dimension / 2, this.diameter);

    return this.pg;
}
```

See the example:

```js
new p5(p5 => {

const rows = 14;
const columns = 14;
const dimension = 40
const height = rows * dimension;
const width = columns * dimension;
const framerate = 60;
const tiles = [];

p5.setup = () => {
    p5.createCanvas(width, height);
    p5.frameRate(framerate);
    for (let r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        for (let c = 0; c < columns; c++) {
            tiles.push(new Tile(p5, c * dimension, r * dimension, dimension, r, c));
        }
    }
};

p5.draw = () => {
    p5.background(200);
    tiles.forEach((tile) => {
        console.log(tile);
        p5.image(tile.update(), tile.x, tile.y);
    });
};
});

class Tile {

    constructor(p5, x, y, dimension, row, column) {
        this.p5 = p5;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.dimension = dimension;
        this.row = row;
        this.column = column;
        this.onFirst = true;
        this.on = p5.color(255, 184, 0);
        this.off = p5.color(26, 17, 16);
        this.diameter = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(dimension, 2) * 2)
        this.pg = this.p5.createGraphics(dimension, dimension)
        this.pg.noStroke();
    }

    update() {
        if (this.diameter < 0) {
            this.diameter = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(this.dimension, 2) * 2);
            this.onFirst = !this.onFirst
        }
        else {
            this.diameter -= 1;
        }
        return this.draw();
    }

    draw() {
        this.pg.fill(this.onFirst ? this.off : this.on);
        this.pg.rect(0, 0, this.dimension, this.dimension);
        this.pg.fill(this.onFirst ? this.on : this.off);
        this.pg.circle(this.dimension / 2, this.dimension / 2, this.diameter);
        return this.pg;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.8.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you! One of those Doh moments :-) This is it finished: https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/Lbs9v8f4/